# Javascript blackjack logic

Tags: javascript

My logic to check if a card has already been used is wrong.

Can someone help me please. (Card comes from a hit function that just picks a new random one).

```
    function checkCard(card) {
    //if card = card in used array, select new card
    for (i = 0; i <= userCards.length; i++) {
        if (userCards[i] == card) {
            //selectCards(card)
            var newRank = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
            var newSuit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            var card = (rank[newRank] + suit[newSuit]);
            checkCard(card);
            //document.getElementById('userCards').innerHTML += "<td id=" + "UserCard" + "><img src=" + "includes/images/cards/" + card + ".png >";
            //userCards[userCards.length] = card;
            //userTotal();
        } else {
            userCards[userIndex] = card;
            document.getElementById('userCards').innerHTML += "<td id=" + "UserCard" + "><img src=" + "includes/images/cards/" + card + ".png >";
            userTotal();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting or problem you're having?

Comment: I don't know what `userIndex` is based on this code and your `for` loop is looping one index too far. You want `i < userCards.length`. Perhaps instead of using `userIndex`, you want `userCards.push(card);`

Comment: @KSFT it still doubles up cards

Comment: @MarcBaumbach Didn't work

Comment: Rather than randomly selecting any card and then checking to see if it has been used, how about creating a collection that includes all the cards in the deck. Then you can randomly select a card from the deck and remove the selected card from the collection. That way you can never select a card that has already been used.

Comment: @Blackwood its for an assesment and needs to shows complex logic and recursion...

Comment: In my opinion simple logic is better than complex logic, but if you are working on an assignment that limits what techniques you can use, you should edit your question to explain those limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a return statement. If you must use recursion try this logic:

```
function checkCard(card)
{    //if card = card in used array, select new card
    for (i = 0; i < userCards.length; i++)
    {
            if (userCards[i] == card)
            {   //selectCards(card)
                var newRank = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
                var newSuit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
                var card = (rank[newRank] + suit[newSuit]);
                checkCard(card);
            return;  // new card was assigned in recursive call above
            }
   }
   // card is unused, assign now
   userCards[userCards.length] = card;
   document.getElementById('userCards').innerHTML += "<td id=" + "UserCard" + "><img src=" + "includes/images/cards/" + card + ".png >";
   userTotal();
   return;      // new card was assigned here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, if you do

```
i <= userCards.length
```

you are going past the index of the array. That should be:

```
i < userCards[i].length
```

Also, I don't understand what your base case is that allows you to stop the recursion. You're just creating some random card, recalling your function, then checking to see if it's in the used array?. If it is, you're making another random card and if it isn't you're adding it to the used array then calling userTotal() with no parameters. Every time you call your function recursively, it's starting at 0 and checking the whole array again.

Your logic to check to see if a card has already been used, other than going past the index, isn't wrong.. but certainly what you're trying to do with the information once you've found it seems wrong.

Try explaining exactly what you're trying to do in a little more detail.